# Trying to query my mongodb to check if a user exists and based off the respose register them

Tags: reactjs, express, react-hooks

I have 2 express routes createUser that adds a new user to my mongodb and getUserByAuth0Id that searches the db for a user. I have tested them with postman and they work fine.

However in my frontend i want to call getUserByAuth0Id to check if a user is already registered or not and add them to my db as per the result.

I am having trouble using the response that returns. Currently I get back "Request failed with status code 404". How can I use this in a conditional?

My React functional element that i am trying to do this in is here:

```
import React, { Component, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useAuth0 } from "@auth0/auth0-react";
import api from "../api";
import "../App.css";

const Homepage = ({ match }) => {
    const { user, isAuthenticated } = useAuth0();

    useEffect(() => {
        async function checkUserExists() {
            if (isAuthenticated) {
                const auth0Id = user.sub.split("|")[1];
                try {
                    const response = await api.getUserByAuth0Id(auth0Id);
                    return response;
                } catch (err) {
                    // console.log(err.message);
                    return err.message;
                }
            }
        }

        async function registerUser() {
            if (checkUserExists() == "No user") {
                register
            }
        }

        registerUser();
    }, []);
```

Here is my api/index.js:

```
import axios from "axios";

const api = axios.create({
    baseURL: "http://localhost:3000/api",
});

export const createQuestion = (payload) => api.post(`/quizzes`, payload);
export const getAllQuestions = () => api.get(`/quizzes`);
export const getQuestionsByQuiz = (quiz) => api.get(`/quizzes/${quiz}`);
export const getQuestionById = (question_id) => api.get(`/quizzes/questions/${question_id}`);
export const updateQuestionById = (question_id, payload) => api.put(`/quizzes/${question_id}/edit`, payload);
export const deleteQuestionById = (question_id) => api.delete(`/quizzes/${question_id}`);
export const createUser = (payload) => api.post(`/users`, payload);
export const getUserByAuth0Id = (Auth0Id) => api.get(`/users/${Auth0Id}`);

const apis = {
    createQuestion,
    getQuestionsByQuiz,
    updateQuestionById,
    deleteQuestionById,
    getAllQuestions,
    getQuestionById,
    createUser,
    getUserByAuth0Id,
};

export default apis;
```

Comment: please provide api file too

Comment: @NishargShah added it

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you are using async functions without `react-thunk`, please add it and after that dispatch your API and it will works

```
export const createUser = async (payload) => await api.post(`/users`, payload);
export const getUserByAuth0Id = async (Auth0Id) => await api.get(`/users/${Auth0Id}`);
```

Comment: In the code snipped I can't see where thunk has been used?

Comment: you need to use as middleware

Comment: if you are using redux only and only then you need to use thunk otherwise this will works